# Have to find the current across the diodes

Tags: diodes

[image]

Resistance 1 is 10k Ohms and it says that D1 has a resistance of 20 ohms and voltage of 0.2V, D2 has a resistance of 15 ohms and voltage of 0.6V.
I'm not sure if both the diodes are on so I dont know how to solve the problem.
Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to replace the diodes with a battery and a resistor and do a loop analysis but I'm not sure I can do that because the answer was that the current was going negative direction of D1 so I dont know

Comment: What's the value of R?

Answer (score 2):

- Start by assuming that pretty much all the `available current` is going into either one diode or the other. Then "test" that assumption.
- So, what is the `available current` from a 100 volt source in series with 10 kΩ? You can estimate that using ohm's law. It doesn't need to be a precise value.
- Using the approximate `available current` "evaluate" what the volt drop would be across one of the diodes due to its inherent diode drop (0.2 volts or 0.6 volts) and its series resistance (20 Ω or 15 Ω).
- Then ask yourself this question: `with the volt drop calculated, will it cause the other diode to conduct any current at all?`. If the answer is `no` then you know all the current flows through the first diode you analysed and non flows through the other.
- If the answer was `yes, it seems as if some current will flow through the other diode` then, put your efforts into working out what that diode will drop when presented exclusively with the available current from the supply and resistor. Then repeat what I did above regarding asking whether the other diode will conduct.

The answer looks clear to me but, I've been around too long not to be tricked by this sort of question. BTW when you say this: -

> *Have to find the current across the diodes*

Current is regarded as flowing `through` and not across something. Voltage is regarded as appearing across something.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. You are right about current flowing through, English is not my first language. But regarding the question, lets say we have about 10mA coming from the main source. The voltage drop across the first diode would be approx 0.4 V if Im correct and the second diode would be 0.75V. Now what I dont understand is when will this cause the other diode to not conduct any correnct? Or is it that only the first one conducts because it has an easier route(Im not sure)? Thanks again for answering

Comment: Only the first diode will conduct. Reason: the 2nd diode needs at least 0.6 volts across it to begin any conduction at all and, given that the 10 mA will drop 0.2 volts plus (20 ohm x 10 mA) = 0.4 volts, then the 2nd diode cannot conduct. Of course, if you chose to analyse the 2nd diode first then you'd see that there would be an anomaly @RisingProject - a different scenario: if the resistor was 1 kohm then 100 mA would be available and, in these circumstances, both diodes would conduct.